# Alterar tabela no mysql

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

Tenho a seguinte situação.

Uma tabela que exibe os resultados pesquisados no mysql, e dentro dessa tabela eu tenho uma coluna onde fica o botão editar.
Como faço para que esse botão edite o conteúdo mostrado naquela linha?

Estou usando o laço `while` para exibí-los e pelo que sei, o laço `while` não faz uma contagem do que foi exibido/encontrado primeiro ou em segundo. Certo?

Por exemplo;
no código abaixo usei o mysql para procurar na tabela "pedido" tudo que tiver a palavra "Aguardando..." na coluna status.
O laço `while` vai exibir um por um em ordem que achar, e exibir mais ou menos assim:

```
ID | Produto   | Valor | Cód. Pedido | Situação      | Editar
 1 | Produto 1 | 1.00  | 321         | Aguardando... | Botão Editar
```

E por assim vai, ID 2, Produto 2 e etc.

Como eu poderia fazer para que o botão no final da tabela editasse dentro do mysql a linha que ele está?

```php
<section class="news">
        <div class="page-reader">
            <h3>Lista de Pedidos <small>atualizado em <?= date("d/m/Y") ?></small></h3>
        </div>
        <table class="table table-striped">
            <tr>
                <td>ID</td>
                <td>Produto</td>
                <td>Valor</td>
                <td>Código do Pedido</td>
                <td>Situação</td>
                <td>Editar Pedido</td>

                <!-- Coloca os dados em um Array -->
                <?php 
                while ($resultado = mysqli_fetch_assoc($dados)) { ?>
            </tr>
                <td><?= $resultado['id']; ?></td>
                <td><?= $resultado['produto']; ?></td>
                <td><?= "R$ ". number_format($resultado['valor'],2); ?></td>
                <td><?= $resultado['pedido']; ?></td>
                <td><?= $resultado['status']; ?></td>
                <td><button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Confirmar</button> <button class="btn btn-danger">Cancelar</button></td>
                <?php
                }
                 ?>
            </table>
    </section>
```

Comment: Editar qual campo?

Comment: Editar o campo Status.
os comandos para edição eu conheço e consigo fazer, porem eu só sei fazer caso eu pegue a variável enviada via post ou get.

Comment: Então vc tem uma lista de N registros e todos com um botão para alterar o status apenas, correto, com clique e update sem reload na página. Você consegue fazer isso com jQuery.

Comment: Veja se essa [**resposta**](http://stackoverflow.com/a/14217926/1244639) ajuda você.

Comment: Papa Charlie, tentei acompanhar o topico que você me passou porem não consegui e acho que não é aquilo que estou precisando.
acho que você não entendeu a minha solicitação.

Comment: Eu não sei o que pode ter gerado o tal aviso de "ofensivo", pode ser algum bug do sistema. Se ocorrer novamente, por favor tire um screenshot e sinalize o post indicando o link da imagem, para que um moderador possa avaliar. Deixei a pergunta como o Victor havia deixado, pois considerei esse o melhor estado dela. Quanto à resposta, por favor tenha paciência. As pessoas que ajudam aqui são todas voluntárias, mas cedo ou tarde você consegue uma resposta. Obrigado.

Answer (score 1):

Bom Rafael, a alternativa mais fácil seria gerar um botão editar por cada linha.
Ou seja.

Gere um botão no `while` ou um `<a>` e passe a url de edição junto com o `id` retornado na consulta

Exemplo:

```
<a href="editar.php?linha=$resultado['id']" />
```